# How to retrieve post request that contain xml from another application using ASP.NET rest api

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rest

I am trying to write a REST webservice api the will retreive xml data from a post request in another application.

Post Request:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\" ?>< PaymentNotification >< SessionID > 000001100913103301000000000001 </ SessionID > < RequestorID > 0000000001 </ RequestorID > < PayerPhoneNumber > 08060000000 </ PayerPhoneNumber > </ PaymentNotification >\r\n";
    // "construct your xml request message as required by that method along with parameters";
    string url = "http://localhost:8921/api/billpayment";

    postXMLData(url, xmlMessage);
}

public void postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
{

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);

    req.ContentType = "text/xml";
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }

    string response = "";

    using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

Get Request:

```
public class BillPaymentController : ApiController
{
    private const string URL = "http://localhost:8921/api/billpayment";
    private string urlParameters = "?api_key={55EB9B66-7B89-4FB2-AE6B-6FEAA78AC10C}";
    // POST api/billpayment
    // POST api/values
    public string GetRequest([FromBody]string value)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body. Blocking!
            var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BillPaymentClass>>().Result;
            foreach (var d in dataObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.MerchantName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

But i am having this error:

The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed on the Post Request method, also the Get Request not working. tried to fix this, but no luck yet, any help will be appeciated

Comment: You are using different content types in each end point - `text/xml` and `application/xml`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @DigiFriend, i was just trying out this, even when i have used same content type, it is still not working

Comment: Normally I debug these issue with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Try connecting using an IE using the URL http://localhost:8921/api/billpayment?api_key={55EB9B66-7B89-4FB2-AE6B-6FEAA78AC10C}.  Capture results with sniffer.  Then repeat using you c# application.  Usually issue is you need to add a missing header in the c# application that the IE will automatically add.

Comment: @jdweng, I have tried your suggestion yet no luck

Comment: Did you get results with IE?  Did you see any differences in headers?  Only look at html packets.  You may have to delete cookies.  The IE may be getting a certificate and going to a different IP address.  Also check if the header is http 1.1 instead of http 1.0.  Net doesn't support 1.1.  So in the header you must send 1.0.  Finally check if status is 200 done.  IE will send multiple requests until 200 done is returned in response.

Comment: @jdweng, I dont know how to use IE, I only know how to test with Postman

Comment: Just add the URL to any IE address box.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will capture the messages from the Ethernet.  You can download these sniffers for free.  The sniffers are not the same a postman. A sniffer give different info.